# Why does Graphviz/Dot act so weirdly to this particular code?

Tags: graphviz, dot, graph-visualization

I am using GraphViz 2.28 [(the current stable version)](http://www.graphviz.org/Download_windows.php) on Windows 7, and Graphviz/Dot crashes for the following code.

```
digraph G {
ranksep = 1.0; size = "10,10";
{
    node [shape = plaintext, fontsize = 20];
    GAWM1 -> GAWM2 -> 0;
}

node [shape = box];
{rank = same;0;wx1;wx2;rx1;}

wx1 -> wx2;
wx2 -> rx1;
wx1 -> rx1[color = blue];

subgraph struct
{
    node [shape = record];
    rx11 [shape = record, label = "rx1 | [x=[wx2]]"];
}
{rank = same; GAWM1; "rx11";}

// W'WR Order:
wx2 -> wx1[style = dashed, color = red, label = "1"]; }
```

Things become weird when I perform some experiments on this example:

1. It works well when *only* the last statement "wx2 -> wx1[style = dashed, color = red, label = "1"];" is removed;
2. It works well when *only* the eighth line "{rank = same;0;wx1;wx2;rx1;}" is removed;
3. It also works well when *only* the label (that is ", label = "1"") in the last statement is removed.

I have reported the problem to [Graphviz Issue Tracker](http://www.graphviz.org/mantisbt/view.php?id=2243), without reply yet. Could you help to find out the reason?

Thank you.

Comment: I've tried your script and ran into a crash of dot.exe and gvedit.exe. Circo.exe and Neato.exe work OK on this sample.

Comment: @AxelKemper Thank for your feedback. However, the statements about Circo and Neato in Graphviz website do not make sense to me. Could you  explain what should I do if I want to use Circo or Neato? Thanks again.

Comment: Graphviz is offering several related but different layout engines. Circo is my favorite when the graph nodes can be nicely displayed in circular arrangements. See http://www.graphviz.org/   Your sample includes a "subgraph". Therefore, you are probably tied to "dot.exe" ("'hierarchical' or layered drawings of directed graphs. This is the default tool to use if edges have directionality.")

Answer (score 0):

The following variation of your script does **not** crash:

```
digraph G {
ranksep = 1.0; size = "10,10";
{
    node [shape = plaintext, fontsize = 20];
    GAWM1 -> GAWM2 -> 0;
}
node [shape = box];
{rank = same;0;wx1;wx2;rx1;}
wx1 -> wx2;
wx2 -> rx1;
wx1 -> rx1[color = blue];
subgraph struct
{
    node [shape = record];
    rx11 [shape = record, label = "rx1 | [x=[wx2]]"];
}
{rank = same; GAWM1; "rx11";}
// W'WR Order:
//wx2 -> wx1[style = dashed, color = red, label = "1"]; 
wx2 -> wx1 [style=dashed, color=red];
}
```

Looks like a bug with the `label` of the short edge between `wx1` and `wx2`.

Comment: Yes, I have done such experiments and mentioned them in my problem. However, I want to keep the label, indicating something important in my situation. Any other suggestions? Thank you. (I will try Circo and Neato.)